# EF Core Rowversion Concurrency Check Not Handle DbConcurrency Error

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework-core, abp, optimistic-concurrency

I have a project that I developed with EF Core and react. What I want is to be able to give the second person an "updated before" error if two different users open the screen at the same time and update the same data at different times. But when I apply it as in the pictures, it does not catch any errors and updates the db. A unique new rowversion is also assigned to the db.

[implementation of what I want in the console app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OPEtW.png)

[dbcontext](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XHMyE.png)

[appservice screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ug88g.png)

[entity screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NbTsf.png)

[rowversion column](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUEXk.png)

The points I updated in my project while implementing.

on modelcreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<User>().Property(e => e.RowVersion)
    .IsRequired()
    .IsRowVersion()
    .IsConcurrencyToken();
```

entity:

```
  public class User : AbpUser<User>
    {
        [Timestamp]
        public byte[] RowVersion { get; set; }
}
```

the code i expect to give an error:

```
 public override async Task<UserDto> UpdateAsync(UserDto input) {

        CheckUpdatePermission();

        //input.RowVersion = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 7, 215 };

        var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(input.Id);

        //MapToEntity(input, user);

        //user.UserName = "hh";

        //user.RowVersion = new byte[] { 1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 9, 85};
        user.RowVersion[1] =55;

        try
        {
            CheckErrors(await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user));
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            throw new UserFriendlyException(e.Message);
        }

        if (input.RoleNames != null)
        {
            CheckErrors(await _userManager.SetRolesAsync(user, input.RoleNames));
        }

        return await GetAsync(input);
    }
```

Comment: Post any code or errors as *text*. Images can't be copied, compiled, tested or googled

Comment: Have you checked the Microsoft docs and tutorials? [Handling Concurrency Conflicts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/concurrency?tabs=data-annotations) and [Tutorial: Handle concurrency - ASP.NET MVC with EF Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/data/ef-mvc/concurrency?view=aspnetcore-7.0) ?

Comment: There's no EF code in those pictures. There's no DbContext configuration or table schema. Modifying the `rowversion` *breaks* optimistic concurrency. The `rowversion` value is meant to be modified automatically by the database, not client applications. That's the entire point of optimistic concurrency - if anything else changed the row since it was loaded, the client will reject the changes. Without a `rowversion` EF will compare all column values for differences

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos A rowversion column is created in the database and it changes automatically in every update process. My problem is that even if I update with an incorrect rowversion, the dbupdateconcurrency error does not appear. thanks

Comment: Again, post text, not images. You haven't posted posted any EF code or DbContext configuration. Perhaps the DbContext doesn't even have optimistic concurrency enabled. ABP isn't Entity Framework, it's a third party library with a lot of quirks. A DbContext is a Unit-of-Work already, so what is that `UnitOfWork(transaction:false)` attribute supposed to do? Have you tried using EF directly? Eg write a unit test or console application, create your DbContext, load an entry, modify the rowversion and save?

Comment: In short EF and optimistic concurrency work. The documentation examples work. What does this question's code do differently? We can't guess

Comment: You can create an example that doesn't require a database if you use the [in-memory provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/testing/testing-without-the-database#in-memory-provider) or SQLite in in-memory mode. This will allow people to copy your code, test it and find out what's wrong and how to fix it

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I can capture concurrency by writing a console application. I added unitofwork while experimenting. I don't even think there is a need to write anything to the dbcontext. but to try, I added the picture that I specified as rowversion in dbcontext. still couldn't catch it.

Comment: Post the code instead of describing it. If you think you have an EF problem, write a small example that uses EF code *only* to demonstrate the problem. Don't ask people to type your code and try to guess the missing parts

Comment: @SahinKenanoglu It's a bit frustrating that you keep posting images of code. As explained, there are [good reasons why you shouldn't do that](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question).

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I didn't ask anyone to write code. I threw out the places I updated to add rowversion for understanding the subject. I'm wondering if I need to update anywhere else to add rowversion and see if it works.

Comment: All that said, the only thing here is that you should change `OriginalValue` of the rowversion property, not the property itself.

Comment: The EF Core code you posted (still as image, not as text) works as expected. Which means the problem is in ABP and how it's configured, not EF.

Comment: @GertArnold 
user.RowVersion[1] =55;  Do I need to change the line?

Do you have any idea how I can do this in the updateasync method I added?
thank you.

Comment: Something like `context.Entry(user).Property(x => x.RowVersion).OriginalValue = new byte[8]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using ABP framework (and you use the framework supplied EfCoreRepository base class for your repository implementation) this is all handled for you when your entity implements the `IHasConcurrencyStamp` interface. Use this instead of RowVersion.

Make sure you are assigning the concurrency stamp value to the entities `ConcurrencyStamp` property (supplied by the caller) before calling update on the repository/DbContext.

Comment: https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/Concurrency-Check
https://community.abp.io/posts/handle-concurrency-with-ef-core-in-an-abp-framework-project-with-asp.net-core-mvc-jlkc3w8f

I used the articles. but when I added the Ihasconcurrency interface to my project, it still didn't work. I tested it while updating it giving any wrong text.

Comment: When I apply these documents, a concurrencystamp column is created in the database that changes with each update operation. However, even if I give a wrong stamp value while updating, the update process is performed without any error.

Comment: Are you using the ABP DbContext and repository implementations?

Comment: yes.
DevFrameTemplateDbContext : AbpZeroDbContext<Tenant, Role, User, DevFrameTemplateDbContext>

Comment: Are you using ABP Framework or ABP Zero? That DbContext is not from ABP framework. MyDbContext : AbpDbContext<MyDbContext> is what it should look like for ABP framework

Comment: ım using using ABP Framework

Comment: OK it sounds like this is where your problem is then...you'll need to remove references to ABPZero, and replace with the relevant ABP packages

Answer (score 0):

When I edited the userappservice I specified in the question as follows, rowversion threw the error and my problem was solved. But I don't know if updating with such a method instead of updateasync will cause any problems.

```
[UnitOfWork(isTransactional:false)]
        public override async Task<UserDto> UpdateAsync(UserDto input)
        {
            CheckUpdatePermission();

            var user = await _userManager.GetUserByIdAsync(input.Id);

            var options = new DbContextOptionsBuilder<DevFrameTemplateDbContext>()
                   .UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection("customsqlconnectıonstring"))
                   .Options;

            using (DevFrameTemplateDbContext db = new
                DevFrameTemplateDbContext(options))
            {
                User p = await db.Users.AsNoTracking().FirstAsync(x => x.Id == input.Id);
                p.UserName = "Guncellendiiiiiiii";
                p.RowVersion = new byte[] { 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 39, 22 }; // hatalı verinde error. doğru verince kaydediyor.
                db.Users.Update(p);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            }

            MapToEntity(input, user);

            //try
            //{
                //CheckErrors(await _userManager.UpdateAsync(user));
            //}
            //catch (Exception e)
            //{
                //throw new UserFriendlyException(e.Message);
            //}

            if (input.RoleNames != null)
            {
                CheckErrors(await _userManager.SetRolesAsync(user, input.RoleNames));
            }

            return await GetAsync(input);
        }
```

Looking forward to your comments to make this working method short enough.